# Boost crashes in standalone application

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, exe, codeblocks

I have troubles using Boost in standalone .exe application.

I am using CodeBlocks IDE with minGW compiler and Boost version 1.67. Under build options->search directories->compiler i have linked $(#boost), and under Linker $(#boost.lib).

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree tree;
    try
    {
        read_ini("C:\\Users\\M0097932\\Desktop\\firstTest\\torque_trac2_L0.eds", tree);
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
    for (auto& section : tree) //iterate over tree and print all entries
    {
        std::cout << '[' << section.first << "]\n";
        for (auto& key : section.second)
            std::cout << key.first << "=" << key.second.get_value<std::string>() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Done" << std::endl;
}
```

The application is working ok if I run it through IDE (it prints everything and exits with status 0). When I run .exe file from \bin\Debug, the program crashes and I don't catch any exception ("[file] has stopped working"). It crashes when calling read_ini() function (I know this because I don't see "test" in cmd).

Why is application crashing and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Some additional information, as requested.

INI file: C:\Users\M0097932\Desktop\firstTest\torque_trac2_L0.eds

```
[1018]
ParameterName=Identity object
ObjectType=0x9
SubNumber=3

[1018sub0]
ParameterName=Number of entries
ObjectType=0x7
DataType=0x0005
AccessType=ro
DefaultValue=3
PDOMapping=0
LowLimit=1
HighLimit=4

[1018sub1]
ParameterName=Vender ID
ObjectType=0x7
DataType=0x0007
AccessType=ro
DefaultValue=0x0400005A
PDOMapping=0
```

If I run .exe program through cmd ("DataGetter.exe") no error shows when the program crashes.

If I put "g++ DataGetter.exe" in cmd, I get loads of errors (but I'm not sure I'm supposed to run .exe file like this)

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf
Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2a0): multiple definition of `_mingw32_init_mainargs'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2a0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x2e0): multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2e0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x300): multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x300): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x320): multiple definition of `atexit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x320): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x330): multiple definition of `_onexit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x330): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x340): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x430): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0xf0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e54): multiple definition of `_imp___ZSt4cerr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e54): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e8c): multiple definition of `_imp___ZTVSt9exception'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e8c): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e88): multiple definition of `_imp___ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e88): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `_argc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.bss+0x4): first definedhere
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `_argv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.bss+0x0): first definedhere
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e58): multiple definition of `_imp___ZSt4cout'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e58): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e7c): multiple definition of `_imp___ZTISt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e7c): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e80): multiple definition of `_imp___ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e80): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e84): multiple definition of `_imp___ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1e84): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1c74): multiple definition of `_imp___ZNSt12placeholders2_1E'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.idata+0x1c74): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Could not find abbrev number 84.
DataGetter.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.eh_frame+0xb8): multiple definition of `__EH_FRAME_BEGIN__'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.eh_frame+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What's the contents of this "ini" file? If you use a very simple and basic "ini" file, does it work then?

Comment: It is test ini file, 22 lines long. It works if I run app from IDE.

Comment: Did you put boost's dlls in the same folder your application runs from ?

Comment: Can you please *show* the file to us? Maybe it has some contents that leads to bugs happening in Boost (probably due to uninitialized variables)? To find such bugs one must first be able to replicate the problem, and right now we can't do that.

Comment: Without an error sounds a bit weird, boost normally throws an error if something wrong is happening. Try to start your program from a console window to see wether you can receive a boost error. You also could have permission issues, start your program as Admin to eliminate this.

Comment: A note about you not being able to catch the crash, the `try ... catch` construct only catches C++ exceptions that are thrown (with `throw`) from C++ code. There are maybe thousands of other causes that a program can crash, and those generally can't be caught by C++ code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure thing, I edited my question and put there INI file there. I don't think you can replicate the error, because we have different compilers and flags and all (tbh i don't know much about that), but if it's helpful to you, I'm ok with it.

Comment: @JulianH I edited my question to add information what happens if I run through console window. Hope it will help you.